# My fullcalendar scheduler view ressource forget one ressource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm a beginner with FullCalendar, I need to develop a calendar with schedular view with vertical ressources. My problem is when I want to insert ressources objects in my calendar, FullCalendar display only 14 ressources while I have 15 ressources. All the time my calendar forget one ressource.

See my code to insert ressources :

```
//Fetch all users from database
    function fetchAllUsers() {
        schedulerService.fetchAllUsers()
            .then(
            function(d) {
                self.users = d;
                for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
                {             
                     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addResource', {
                        id: d[i].nom,
                        title: d[i].prenom + " " + d[i].nom,
                    });
                }
            },
            function(errResponse) {
                console.error('Error while fetching activities');
            }
        );
    }
```

Please see the array object (with no data because I can't publish this data on Stackoverflow) :

```
[
    {
        "id": 601,
        "nom": "TEST4",
        "prenom": "TEST2",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nom": "TEST8",
        "prenom": "TEST6",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nom": "TEST7",
        "prenom": "TEST3",
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "nom": "TEST45",
        "prenom": "TEST6",
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nom": "TEST23",
        "prenom": "TEST12",
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "nom": "TEST20",
        "prenom": "TEST25",
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "nom": "TEST74",
        "prenom": "TEST68",
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "nom": "TEST78",
        "prenom": "TEST87",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "nom": "TEST456",
        "prenom": "TEST568",
    },
    {
        "id": 401,
        "nom": "TEST75",
        "prenom": "TEST454",
    },
    {
        "id": 501,,
        "nom": "TEST42",
        "prenom": "TEST125",
    },
    {
        "id": 617,
        "nom": "TEST754",
        "prenom": "TEST7512",
    },
    {
        "id": 619,
        "nom": "TEST45",
        "prenom": "TEST78",
    },
    {
        "id": 611,
        "nom": "TRUC",
        "prenom": "TEST",
    },
    {
        "id": 604,
        "nom": "TOTO",
        "prenom": "TUTUT",
    }
]
```

(length : 15)

Real IDs of my data :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XChQT.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: There's nothing obvious wrong with your code. Please show us the JSON data (i.e. the content of `d`) so we can check. Thanks.

Comment: {
        "id": 1,
        "matricule": "",
        "nom": "",
        "prenom": "",
        "poste": "",
        "telephone": "",
        "email": "",
        "manager": "",
        "equipe": "",
        "exterieur": "",
        "type_utilisateur": ""
    },

Comment: that's only a single object...yet you are complaining about a difference of 14 and 15 items. That makes no sense. Isn't `d` an array? Please _edit the question_ (don't add code in the comments) and include the whole response (formatted to be readable), thanks. Also all the values in your example are empty, so if you use some of those for the id and title property (which you do) then clearly nothing will be visible on the calendar.

Comment: The JSON that I give you is clear because I can publish on stackoverflow the data. It's an example of my ressource object. The 'd' is an array of ressource object

Comment: So...please show me the array as requested. You're complaining about something related to the array length, not an individual object, so we need to see the array. You can edit your question easily and use the tools to format it. There's no problem with that. Look for the "edit" button at the bottom of your question. If you can't show the array (the real one which gives you a problem, not an invented example, although you can anonymise the names if you like), then we can't really help you much.

Comment: It's no use because it only has 3 items. The whole issue is related to the **length**. You claim it's 15 items but I can't prove that. And I can't prove that the reason you don't see anything is not because the values are simply blank. Please just anonymise the parts of your data which are sensitive. TBH all we need to see are the `nom` and `prenom` properties which are the things you're using. They can be anonymised, but they need to be populated in the same way that they are in your real dataset. You can remove the rest of the properties, it will save time and space on the question.

Comment: Ok thanks. Simply it's because you have two resources with the same ID - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you have two resources with the same `nom`, and since you use `nom` as the resource ID, it fails because you cannot have duplicate IDs - if you did, fullCalendar would not be able to distinguish between them when doing things like adding to the calendar, or dragging events.

See https://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/74 which demonstrates that issue - the second resource with nom: "TEST45" does not get added to the calendar.

Assuming that the `id` field in your objects *is* unique, I suggest you use that instead as the resource ID. One tiny change to your code is all that's needed:

```
for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
{             
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addResource', {
    id: d[i].id, // use your id field as the resource ID
    title: d[i].prenom + " " + d[i].nom
  }, true);
}
```

Now see https://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/75 which is using your `id` field as the resource ID. All the resources are present on the calendar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I try it I have always the same problem. However the ID are not duplicates

Comment: Please find attached in my post a screeshot with my IDs

Comment: Sorry, but please visit the second JSFiddle link in the answer. I used exactly the same IDs as in your screenshot. If your IDs are not duplicates then it will work, I have proved that. Either you did not change your code correctly, or your real data must still have some duplicate entries.

Comment: I tried your code in my project with exactly the same as your Fiddle and I have the same problem. But, I've seen that you use FullCalendarV1.9.0 and I use FullCalendarv1.3.0-beta maybe it's for that